# GeoServer Web UI Tables - Default amount of items to show

Tags: geoserver

As it stands, all of the HTML tables in GeoServer only load 25 items at a time. Is it possible to set this to a higher number so I don't have to go through numerous pages to find my items?

Aware that the search bar exists also - am hoping there's a quick bit of code I can change in the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It currently seems to be a private static final variable in [`GeoServerTablePanel.java`](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/web/core/src/main/java/org/geoserver/web/wicket/GeoServerTablePanel.java#L57), so it would take a little bit of work to expose it as a configurable parameter or system variable.

Comment: Will leave it then. Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: go on, scratch that itch! or at least put it in the issue tracker in case some one else is looking for an easy PR to boost their CV.